# Error when building for Release: “Manifest references file 'MyProject.exe' which is not part of the payload.”

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm having this error when I'm trying to create a Release Build for "MyProject":

> Manifest references file 'MyProject.exe' which is not part of the payload.

The error is in Package.appxmanifest file. I don't understand how manifest can reference target executable. It makes no sense at all.

I have no problems in Debug mode. I tried building sample projects i.e [UWP app samples in Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) in Release and it builds with no error.

Comment: When you unload your project and then edit it. You will find that yourproject.csproj is actually another manifest file and you can find this line  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'"> it is the place where your release mode is setted. This is why it report this kind of error. You need to tell us what you have done so that we can understand why you failed in release mode.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
This is what I have in .csproj file:  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
         <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
 <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP</DefineConstants> <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008;</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain></PropertyGroup>

Comment: sorry for the poor formatting

Comment: I tried removing `<UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>` now I can create build but I want to know why DotNetNativeToolchain line is causing error.

Comment: When we upload UWP app to the store, it will compile use .NET Native in order to make the app run more quickly with the help of native code. So in release mode actually this option will be checked by default. So actually we have to resolve this issue if the app need to be upload to store. Can you enable .NET native when debug so that we can understand the real problem. You can find this option by right click your project->Build->Choose debug configuration->Then click Compile with .NET Native tool chain.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue??